# What is the name of a portion of video between camera changes?

Tags: terminology

Most movies consist of short portions, within which a picture is changing smoothly, but between which picture changes drastically. May be camera point of view changes or entire scene  is replaced.

What is the name of such portions and their margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing shots.  A scene is composed of one or more shots covering a consistent location and time.  Each separate clip within the scene is simply referred to as a shot.  The shot changes any time that the camera position is moved.  Technically, if you are on a close up shot and cut to a wide angle and then cut back to a close up, they would both be part of the same close up shot if they were from a continuous clip, but I've never heard any other term applied to the smallest unit of continuous video.

If the shots transition directly from one to the other without any interlude, this is referred to as a cut.  The term comes from the film days when one would cut the film and splice it together with the first frame of the next scene.

Answer (score 1):

It's take or shot ("Einstellung" in German) and cut ("Schnitt")

Comment: Are you sure about the term take being applicable here?  I've only ever heard it applied to the actual filming, not the shot in the final edit.

Comment: I always took 'shot' and 'take' for being synonymous, but I'm not a native speaker, I may be wrong.

Comment: ok, as a native speaker doing moderate amounts of video production, I have never once heard of a shot referred to interchangeably.  Take is a particular filming (and multiple shots may be filmed in the same take) A shot is a particular angle of a scene.